# jQuery Reveal modal don't support Iframe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, zurb-foundation

I'm using Foundation 4 with the Reveal modal feature.
I'm able to show an iframe with youtube video but I can't display other website inside the iframe.
Any Idea

http://jsfiddle.net/3Jrch/

```
<div data-reveal class="reveal-modal" id="videoModal">
  <h2>This should have iframe</h2>
  <div class="flex-video" style="display: block;">
    <iframe width="420" height="315" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="" src="https://www.google.com" data-src="https://www.google.com"></iframe>
  </div>

  <a class="close-reveal-modal">×</a>
</div>        <a class="radius button" data-reveal-id="videoModal" href="#">Example Modal w/Video…</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a known problem with `Google` itself.

```
Refused to display 'https://www.google.com.sg/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=tqgYU7_aEqm9iAfOkoGoDg' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'
```

You can see more information about this known problem here:[Overcoming "Display forbidden by X-Frame-Options"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6666423/overcoming-display-forbidden-by-x-frame-options)

Try to use other page such as: `http://www.apple.com/`

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3Jrch/1/)**